# How to text data from website

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, backend

Hi Im currently developing an app where I have some text which informs the user about something. This information is also on my website and what i want to do is when i change the information on my website I also want the text in my app to change. I know that you can create a backend tableview with for example parse but that's not what Im looking for. I've done som research and think what i need do to is use JSON in some way to display the text from my website in my app. Pleas comment If you don't understand what It s that Im trying to accomplish. If you could either link a tutorial or explain how/if this is possible I would appreciate It very much!

Comment: tldr; please be more specific/add code etc

Comment: Hi sorry i don't have any code yet that's why Im here

Comment: So come back when you have some code.

Comment: But that's the thing i don't know how to start that's why im asking here

Comment: So you expect people to do the work for you? Do some research, google, try implementing a basic version of what you're trying to achieve - only then we can try helping you.

Comment: And as I wrote in my question I have already done some research

Comment: I'm not complaining at all :-) I'm just saying this is not how this community works.

Comment: @user3748461 the way this works is 1) You learn the basics i.e. tutorials, books etc. 2) You attempt to do some sort of code to resolve your problem. 3) You have a problem, you come on here and specify what the problem is providing the code you have in relation to the problem and you specify what should be happening and what is currently happening. 4) We give the best possible answer based on the information you have supplied us with.

Comment: @user3748461 what we will not do 1) Your homework 2) Write an entire solution for you. 3) Provide you with third-party resources 4) Write the beginnings of your solution so you can continue with it yourself.

Comment: No and I never told anyone to do anything for me and im sorry if that's how It looked. All i wanted to know was if anyone had tried this before or even knew if this is possible at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can make a json call from your app to a url and have a script or file in your website that returns the information you want, this will make it easy to change it in future. then use the same script as the basis ( again using a json call) to get the text for the specific webpage.

It's difficult to answer more specifically since you've mentioned no technology base for your website.

Comment: Thanks now i have some more information to research on.